# How to change screen resolution programmatically

Tags: c#, vb.net, screen-resolution

When my application is loaded system screen resolution needed to change to 1024 * 768. When its closed, it change to the original screen solution.

How to achive this?. Any feasible solution is there? Basically I'm working with vb.net anyway I welcome a solution from C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215412/programmatically-change-screen-resolution

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6810/Dynamic-Screen-Resolution

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There are so many assumptions being made about the target hardware that seem quite scary (e.g. not multi-monitor, not portrait orientation, not going to alt-tab whilst having the application open, not a widescreen monitor, not using large fonts)

Comment: I dont think thats a good idea and I dont think is neccesary at all with winforms

Answer (score 3):

Changing the resolution is more difficult.

This CodeProject describes how to do it in C# 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/changing-display-settings.aspx and you can use this

following website to help you translate the C# code to VB http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

EDIT

here is sample

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Resolution As New ResolutionChanger
  Private OldWidth As UInteger
  Private OldHeight As UInteger

  Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Resolution.SetResolution(OldWidth, OldHeight)
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    OldHeight = CUInt(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
    OldWidth = CUInt(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width)
    Select Case Resolution.SetResolution(800, 600)
      Case ResolutionChanger.ChangeResult.Success
        MsgBox("The Resolution was changed", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
      Case ResolutionChanger.ChangeResult.Restart
        MsgBox("Restart your system to activate the new resolution setting", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
      Case ResolutionChanger.ChangeResult.Fail
        MsgBox("The resolution couldn't be changed", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
      Case ResolutionChanger.ChangeResult.ResolutionNotSupported
        MsgBox("The requested resolution is not supported by your system", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
    End Select
  End Sub

End Class
'
'========== RESOLUTION CHANGER ===============================
'
'
Class ResolutionChanger
  Public Enum ChangeResult
    Success
    Restart
    Fail
    ResolutionNotSupported
  End Enum

  Public Function SetResolution(ByVal Width As UInteger, ByVal Height As UInteger) As ChangeResult
    Dim DevMode As New DEVMODEA
    If User_32.EnumDisplaySettingsA(Screen.PrimaryScreen.DeviceName, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, DevMode) Then
      DevMode.dmPelsWidth = Width
      DevMode.dmPelsHeight = Height
      Dim ReturnValue = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettingsA(DevMode, CDS_TEST)
      If ReturnValue = DISP_CHANGE_FAILED Then
        'The Requested resolution is not supported by the system
        Return ChangeResult.ResolutionNotSupported
      Else
        ReturnValue = User_32.ChangeDisplaySettingsA(DevMode, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY)
        Select Case ReturnValue
          Case DISP_CHANGE_RESTART
            'The resolution cannot be change dynamically on every system
            'Windows 9x and some Laptop (XP,Vista,Windows7) have to reboot.
            Return ChangeResult.Restart
          Case DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL
            'Resolution was changed
            'This is not an assurance that the new resolution will render 
            'proprely on every system. It only means that the registery was
            'updated succesfuly and that the driver have not return any
            'error
            Return ChangeResult.Success
          Case Else
            'An error has caused the resolution not to be changed
            Return ChangeResult.Fail
        End Select
      End If
    End If
  End Function
  '
  '============Region Interop ==============================================
  '
  '
  Private Const ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS As Integer = -1
  Private Const CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY As Integer = 1
  Private Const CDS_TEST As Integer = 2
  Private Const DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL As Integer = 0
  Private Const DISP_CHANGE_RESTART As Integer = 1
  Private Const DISP_CHANGE_FAILED As Integer = -1

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Public Structure DEVMODEA
    'BYTE[32]
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=32, ArraySubType:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)> _
    Public dmDeviceName() As Byte
    Public dmSpecVersion As UShort
    Public dmDriverVersion As UShort
    Public dmSize As UShort
    Public dmDriverExtra As UShort
    Public dmFields As UInteger
    Public Union1 As Anonymous_2338c0fc_03a3_4514_b536_fb9bb5df14c5
    Public dmColor As Short
    Public dmDuplex As Short
    Public dmYResolution As Short
    Public dmTTOption As Short
    Public dmCollate As Short
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=32, ArraySubType:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.I1)> _
    Public dmFormName() As Byte
    Public dmLogPixels As UShort
    Public dmBitsPerPel As UInteger
    Public dmPelsWidth As UInteger
    Public dmPelsHeight As UInteger
    Public Union2 As Anonymous_7557e508_845c_4777_b9f2_a1496c1c7b21
    Public dmDisplayFrequency As UInteger
    Public dmICMMethod As UInteger
    Public dmICMIntent As UInteger
    Public dmMediaType As UInteger
    Public dmDitherType As UInteger
    Public dmReserved1 As UInteger
    Public dmReserved2 As UInteger
    Public dmPanningWidth As UInteger
    Public dmPanningHeight As UInteger
  End Structure

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
  Public Structure Anonymous_2338c0fc_03a3_4514_b536_fb9bb5df14c5
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)> _
    Public Struct1 As Anonymous_a67d541d_da92_408e_8852_89977e56cead
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)> _
    Public Struct2 As Anonymous_d973d7e7_ad4c_4155_86fe_6d2b51ab5f04
  End Structure

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)> _
  Public Structure Anonymous_7557e508_845c_4777_b9f2_a1496c1c7b21
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)> _
    Public dmDisplayFlags As UInteger
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)> _
    Public dmNup As UInteger
  End Structure

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Public Structure Anonymous_a67d541d_da92_408e_8852_89977e56cead
    Public dmOrientation As Short
    Public dmPaperSize As Short
    Public dmPaperLength As Short
    Public dmPaperWidth As Short
    Public dmScale As Short
    Public dmCopies As Short
    Public dmDefaultSource As Short
    Public dmPrintQuality As Short
  End Structure

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Public Structure Anonymous_d973d7e7_ad4c_4155_86fe_6d2b51ab5f04
    Public dmPosition As POINTL
    Public dmDisplayOrientation As UInteger
    Public dmDisplayFixedOutput As UInteger
  End Structure

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
  Public Structure POINTL
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
  End Structure

  Partial Public Class User_32
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="EnumDisplaySettingsA")> _
    Public Shared Function EnumDisplaySettingsA(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute(), System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)> ByVal lpszDeviceName As String, ByVal iModeNum As Integer, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute()> ByRef lpDevMode As DEVMODEA) As <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="ChangeDisplaySettingsA")> _
    Public Shared Function ChangeDisplaySettingsA(<System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute()> ByRef lpDevMode As DEVMODEA, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer
    End Function
  End Class

End Class
```

Comment: i try this code but its not wroking in except. That means am change the resoltuion and run the application but my application did not affected

Answer (score 3):

Although I would hate a desktop program that changes my resolution  and toss it out immediately

But for coding you can use something like this

This API function lets you change display settings:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings(
        ref DEVMODE devMode, int flags);
```

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csdynamicscrres.aspx?df=100&forumid=38736&select=800137) article explains how to use this function