# C# : The type or namespace name 'DEVMODE' could not be found

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm trying to change the screen resolution in C# (there are already several questions in regards to that on StackOverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897847/how-to-change-screen-resolution-programmatically) one). I'm following the links that are given with this question, and I'm trying to implement the solution using the ChangeDisplayFunction.

This ChangeDisplayFunction as a field called **DEVMODE**, but when I use it, it always gives me the error:

> The type or namespace name 'DEVMODE' could not be found.

I'm not even doing anything with it. I only initialized the functions from the user32.dll library from which it comes. I declared everything like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int ChangeDisplaySettings( ref DEVMODE devMode, int flags);
```

I'm rather new to C# so I don't know which namespace I should use to resolve this. I've tried googling it and I looked to the documentation from Microsoft but all of the namespaces it mentioned worked.

Comment: `DEVMODE` is a Type you need to create, See https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.DEVMODE

Comment: Creating a type as described in the link creates even more unknown types (namely DM and POINTL). In any case, it seems strange tat a library knows this type, but you have to define it outside of the library to use it.

Comment: They are also Types that need to be created, use the same site to look them up.

Comment: *"a library knows this type"* - This would be true if you were using a .Net Assembly or COM DLL but you are using a different mechanism (pinvoke) to call user32.dll which is a DLL that simply allows you to call a function it exports, there is no exchange of type information when you do that.

Comment: it now gives me the following error message when running: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DEVMODE' from assembly ... , Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 70 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.