# How to change Screen Resolution For Specific Program

Tags: c#, .net, screen, resolution

**Hi,**

I've seen a program named "Display Changer II By 12noon.com".
It change screen resolution for a specific program like games and other.
I wanted to develop similar program in c#.net is there any hint that i can be
able to change screen resolution for a specific program in .Net.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has been covered before.

[How to change screen resolution programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215412/programmatically-change-screen-resolution)

[Dynamic Screen Resolution source code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6810/Dynamic-Screen-Resolution)

Hopefully these can help.

Comment: I've checked them, but they are not for setting different screen resolution for different program.