# changing screen resolution programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screen-resolution

IDE: VS2010, c#.net 4.0, winforms

My application is build on **1366x768** screen resolution. And I have another samsung LCD, which is having highest resolution -> **1920x1080**, but in option list (Right click Desktop->Screen Resolution) it is not having **1366x768** resolution, So is there any way to force this lcd display to **1366x768** resolution so my application can get fits to that LCD, Operating system is `Windows 7`.

Comment: I do not think tampering with user resolution is a good idea. Personally I will not be happy if an application keeps changing my resolution. Considering people do a lot of stuff on screen at the same time, you will distort every other window. Still you may take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215412/programmatically-change-screen-resolution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a lot by using [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)

```
nircmd.exe setdisplay 1366 768 32
```

Also it is not programmatically but you can [start a Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp) and call this utility.

Forcing the user to change the resolution is not a good practice. Try adapting your design to [support different resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259261/automatically-adjusting-winform-and-controls-to-screen-size).

Also you can not force a monitor to change it's resolution to something it does not support.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed int by [Ferruccio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086) in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215435):

> You can use [EnumDisplayDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609.aspx) to figure out what displays you
>   have available and [EnumDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611.aspx) to get a list of available
>   resolutions for your displays. Use [ChangeDisplaySettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411.aspx) to set
>   the resolution you need.