# Automate screen resolution

Tags: java, jenkins, leanft

I have an automation testing project using LeanFT automation tool (in Java).
Those tests covers UI flows of a web application.

Jenkins job execute those tests nightly on remote slave RDP VM.

I realized that tests sometimes fail, but couldn't spot the exact reason.
After investigation, i found out that if the last user logged in to the VM had resolution different than 1920 X 1080 (for example login to the with laptop with different native resolution) tests are failing.

I am using LeanFT VRI method (Visual Relational Identifiers) in my tests to identify objects which have no ID, meaning identifying objects based on other objects in the DOM (closest on x/y Axis). so this is obviously related to screen resolution.

My question is:
How can i insure my tests start with the needed screen resolution, regardless to the last login resolution ?
I assume i need a way to override the existing resolution using Jenkins parameter or adding some line of code to my testing project to support a case which resolution is different than 1920 x 1080.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking Windows OS here, you can do that by calling some WinAPIs functions.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215412/programmatically-change-screen-resolution), you can use:

> 1. [EnumDisplayDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609.aspx) to figure out what displays you have available
> 2. [EnumDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611.aspx) to get a list of available resolutions for your displays. 
>      3.[ChangeDisplaySettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183411.aspx) to set the resolution you need.

To call those functions in Java you can use the [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna). As they mention:

> The definitive JNA reference (including an overview and usage details) is in the [JavaDoc](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/).  Please read the [overview](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.2.0/javadoc/overview-summary.html#overview_description).  [...] you may find it easier to find answers to already-solved problems on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jna).